# No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use a function to add standard deviation error bars to my ggplot bar graph. In particular, I want to use mean_sdl.

```
ggplot(recall_info) +
 aes(x = Condition, y = pwords) +
  geom_bar(aes(Condition, pwords), position = "dodge", stat = "summary", fun.y = "mean") +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, width=0.05, geom = "errorbar") +
 labs(y = "% of words remembered", title = "Proportion of Words Remembered") +
 theme_light() + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,50)) + 
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("condition1", "condition2")), test = "t.test", map_signif_level=TRUE)
```

And I get the following error:

> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
>   Warning message:
>   Ignoring unknown parameters: fun.y

I don't understand what is wrong. The error bars I get on my graph are clearly wrong - they go off the graph entirely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `geom_bar` line should probably be `stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="col")`, but hard to be certain without a data sample to test with.

Comment: Yep.  unquote `mean` in `geom_bar`.  You may also get a warning that `fun.y=` is depreciated (in which case you just use `fun=`), but it will work with either `fun.y` or `fun`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Removing the quotations around mean and doing fun= worked.

Answer (score 9):

Just change the

```
fun.y = "mean"
```

to

```
fun = mean
```