# Error bars look weird in ggplot2 (continuos Y x categorical X) - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, visualization, line-plot

I'm ploting a continuos Y variable against a 2-level categorical variable with ggplot2, grouping by another 2-level categorical variable, but the **error bars** look weird (they're all connected to each other, I don't know why...) **edit: I've added a reproducible dataset below :)**

- Plot: (there's no division between the error bars...)

[image: my plot]

- code:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = CATEGORIES, y = CONTINUOSY)) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = MY_GROUP), position = position_dodge(width = 0)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, shape = 4) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = MYGROUP, linetype = MY_GROUP, color = MY_GROUP),
               geom = "line", size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Categories A and B",
       y = "Continuos Y",
       title = "This is my plot") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        legend.background = element_rect(color = "black"),  
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"), 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold"))
```

I also get this error: [as here, but it didn't help me...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669169/no-summary-function-supplied-defaulting-to-mean-se)

```
No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
Warning message:
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

- How can I solve this and correct the error bars? Any ideas would be much appreciated!
  Thanks in advance :)
- Edit:

[reproducible dataset here on Git](https://github.com/Larissa-Cury/datapost2309.git)

- trying `dput` for the first time:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(PARTICIPANTS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), CONT_Y = c(19.44, 20.07, 19.21, 
16.35, 11.37, 12.82, 19.42, 18.94, 19.59, 20.01, 19.7, 17.92, 
18.78, 19.21, 19.27, 18.46, 19.52, 20.02, 16.19, 19.97, 13.83, 
15.93, 14.79, 21.55, 18.8, 19.42, 19.27, 19.37, 17.14, 14.45, 
17.63, 20.01, 20.28, 17.93, 19.36, 20.15, 16.06, 17.04, 19.16, 
20.1, 16.44, 18.39, 18.01, 19.05, 18.04, 19.69, 19.61, 16.88, 
19.02, 20.42, 18.27, 18.43, 18.08, 17.1, 19.98, 19.43, 19.71, 
19.93, 20.11, 18.41, 20.31, 20.1, 20.38, 20.29, 13.6, 18.92, 
19.05, 19.13, 17.75, 19.15, 20.19, 18.3, 19.43, 19.8, 19.83, 
19.53, 16.14, 21.14, 17.37, 18.73, 16.51, 17.51, 17.06, 19.42
), CATEGORIES = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), MY_GROUP = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-84L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: @Quinten , hi, I don't know how to use dput, so I've upload on GitHub. I'm going to edit the post!

Comment: `dput(data)` will output a string that others can evaluate to recreate the `data` object.

Comment: @merv and Quinten , all right! See if I got it right? Is it just that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you color the error bars, you could see that they just overlap. You could change the transparency if you want. Because you don't use `fun` in two of your `stat_summary` calls, it takes the default `mean_se`. Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = CATEGORIES, y = CONT_Y)) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = MY_GROUP, color = MY_GROUP), 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, shape = 4) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = MY_GROUP, linetype = MY_GROUP, color = MY_GROUP),
               fun = mean, geom = "line", size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0)) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Categories A and B",
       y = "Continuos Y",
       title = "This is my plot") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        legend.background = element_rect(color = "black"),  
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"), 
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face = "bold"))
#> No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: hi, thank you! but a) insn't their size too big? (I mean, should they be this big?) and b) is there a way that I can add a space between the lines to avoid overlapping?