# should we plot error bars or confidence intervals from estimated means?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, variance, line-plot

This post is an update of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73831029/error-bars-look-weird-in-ggplot2-continuos-y-x-categorical-x-r). Back then, I believe I was ploting the standard error (SE) associated with the raw mean. Now I've fit a data into a [model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603792/whats-the-appropriate-effect-size-estimate-and-power-analysis-for-post-hoc-re?noredirect=1#comment1121366_603792). I'm wondering **If I should stick with the previous version**, or **If I should instead plot the estimated marginal means of the model**?

- from `emmeans`, I get:

```
group <- emmeans(mod1,~ MY_GROUP|YEAR) 
year <- emmeans(mod1,~YEAR|MY_GROUP) 

t <- data.frame(year) %>% full_join(data.frame(group))

t
  YEAR MY_GROUP   emmean        SE       df lower.CL upper.CL
1 2020       G1 17.61143 0.4025956 75.91634 16.80958 18.41328
2 2021       G1 18.75524 0.4025956 75.91634 17.95339 19.55709
3 2020       G2 18.52619 0.4025956 75.91634 17.72434 19.32804
4 2021       G2 19.06762 0.4025956 75.91634 18.26577 19.86947
>
```

- Should I plot CI's instead?

```
t %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = YEAR, y = emmean)) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = MY_GROUP, linetype = MY_GROUP, color = MY_GROUP),
               geom = "line", size = 1, position = position_dodge(width = 0)) +
  # stat_summary(aes(group = MY_GROUP), geom = "errorbar", size = 0.5) +
  stat_summary(aes(group = MY_GROUP, color = MY_GROUP), 
               position = position_dodge(width = 0), fun.data = mean_se) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin= lower.CL, ymax= upper.CL), color= 'black', width=.1,
                                 position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  # stat_summary(fun = mean, shape = 4) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(G1 = "black", G2 =  "black"), guide = 'none') +
  scale_linetype(name = 'MY_GROUP:')

No summary function supplied, defaulting to `mean_se()`
Warning message:
Removed 4 rows containing missing values (`geom_segment()`).
```

- A) What would be the best and **more informative** approach? Thanks.
- B) I still get the warning message, but now I'm ploting the CI, not `mean_se()`, right?
- data + details: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603792/whats-the-appropriate-effect-size-estimate-and-power-analysis-for-post-hoc-re?noredirect=1#comment1121366_603792)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not throwing out the baby with the bathwater by wrapping everything in `data.frame()`. For confidence intervals, just do

```
plot(group + year, CIs = TRUE)
```